# error in Undefined function 'insertObjectAnnotation' in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-cvst

i try to apply code for face detection and tracking in matlab but unfortunately this error prompted up

i use matlab R2012a

this is the code i tried

```
faceDetector = vision.CascadeObjectDetector();
videoFileReader = vision.VideoFileReader('visionface.avi');
videoFrame      = step(videoFileReader);
bbox            = step(faceDetector, videoFrame);
videoOut = insertObjectAnnotation(videoFrame,'rectangle',bbox,'Face');
```

and this is the error :

```
Undefined function 'insertObjectAnnotation' for input
arguments of type 'single'.
```

please help .

Comment: Enter `whos videoFrame` into the command prompt and report what it says under "Class".

Comment: i do it and it says    'single'  under   "Class" !

Comment: Next, try `which insertObjectAnnotation` at the command prompt. This checks that the function actually exists on a path where Matlab can find it.

Comment: Dear Salam, did you get a solution for the problem. I am having same problem. please help.

Answer (score 1):

The function insertObjectAnnotation was introduced to Matlab in R2012b. it is not available for matlab R2012a

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `videoFrame` is of type `single` which isn't a valid input type. Most matlab functions expect their inputs to be of type `double`.   Try casting `videoFrame` to a `double`:

```
ideoOut = insertObjectAnnotation( double(videoFrame), 'rectangle', bbox, 'Face');
```

Comment: HI Slayton, I am having the same problem. When I use double(videoFrame) it give error- Undefined function 'insertObjectAnnotation' for input
arguments of type 'double'. can you please help

Comment: here is a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15540160/undefined-function-insertobjectannotation-in-matlab

Comment: insertObjectAnnotation was added in R2012b, and it does work for single and double.

Answer (score 0):

insertObjectAnnotation is working for windows environtment under the Computer Vision System Toolbox. It doesn't work in ubuntu.

Comment: It should work for Linux as well, assuming you have R2012b or later.

Answer (score 0):

The function `insertObjectAnnotation` did not exist in R2012a. It was added in R2012b.  If you still have R2012a, you can use `vision.ShapeInserter` and `vision.TextInserter` system objects to annotate your image.  They are not quite as convenient as `insertObjectAnnotation`, but they will do the job.