# Undefined function 'insertObjectAnnotation'

Tags: matlab, matlab-cvst

I have recently installed `matlab R2012a`  when i type `ver` i see

```
Computer Vision System Toolbox                        Version 5.0        (R2012a)
```

along with other toolboxes. I suppose this means that the toolbox is installed?
When i try to run

```
videoOut = insertObjectAnnotation( double(videoFrame), 'rectangle', bbox, 'Face');
```

Similar question ["error in Undefined function 'insertObjectAnnotation' in matlab"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13867635/error-in-undefined-function-insertobjectannotation-in-matlab) suggested using `double` but when i run it i get

`Undefined function 'insertObjectAnnotation' for input arguments of type 'double'.`

So i run `which insertObjectAnnotation` after which i get `'insertObjectAnnotation' not found.`

What does it mean and how should i solve this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [error in Undefined function 'insertObjectAnnotation' in matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13867635/error-in-undefined-function-insertobjectannotation-in-matlab)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `insertObjectAnnotation` was [introduced to Matlab in R2012b](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/release-notes.html). Therefore, it is not available in your version of Matlab.

Comment: ok... thanks... is there any way to update matlab or the toolbox to the latest version so that i don't have to pay again?

Comment: @RohanKandwal: If you are subscribed to the Software Mainenance Service, you will get updates for free. In other words, no there is no way to upgrade versions without paying *something*.